# Automatically populate attribute table based on feature location within another feature?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, attribute-table, overlay

I have two datasets. One of all the suburbs in a particular state. The other of all the housing lots across the state. I want to add a field to the lot feature class' Attribute table which can then use some tool to automatically populate which suburb each lot falls within.

Is there a simple process to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a [spatial join](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm) you can append the attributes of one dataset to the other. If you are trying to fill a particular field you can then just copy it across using the field calulator